# iOS - Swift - Spacing between cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add spacing between my cells in a UITableView.
The solutions I read on here were as follows:

- Add an empty cell between each real cell (%2 condition)
- Use Sections instead of Rows
- Put the cell's content in a container UIView and make the cell's height bigger than the container view.
- Adding padding using the separatorInset property via code which doesn't work because Apple stated that only the left and right separatorInset are taken into consideration.

As you can see, all those solutions are pretty much hacking solution, each has its own disadvantage.

What's the real way adding spacing? I can't believe such a simple thing can be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the real way adding spacing?

There is *no* "real way" of adding spacing between cells of a table view. 
A table view's cells are *always* adjacent to one another; all you can do is provide the *illusion* that they are not, which is what your "solutions" all do. I can think of other, less "hacking" approaches — what I do is simply draw each cell's contents only partially, leaving a space between the drawing inside one cell and the drawing inside the next — but it's still just an illusion.

If you want the true flexibility to position your cells an actual distance from one another, use a collection view instead; that's what it's for. It generalizes table view so that layout of cells is fully in your hands.